# Rails has many association validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I need to check presence validation for the associated attributes every time when the parent model gets updated.

In my user.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :histories
has_many :histories
```

I need to add validation for the histories when the user model gets updated, I know `accepts_nested_attributes` will take care of the validations while adding the user through forms, I need to check for the validation every time the user model gets updated even in the console,

If I add

```
validates :histories, presence: true
```

It will check for record in the histories table, If any record available for the user It will skip the validation for histories, I need to validate every time the object gets updated. Is there any way to validate whether the new record is being created when updating the parent model?

Comment: You can always add a custom validator or a custom validation method if activerecord's default validator does not fit your needs. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think what you may be looking for is [`validates_associated`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :histories

  # validates that the association exists
  validates :histories, presence: true

  # validates that the objects in the associated collection are themselves valid
  validates_associated :histories
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the `validates :attribute, presence: true` validator is meant to validate first-class attributes on the model, not relationships. Such things like on a User class `validates :email, presence: true`, is where it works best.

Is your goal to validate the has_many relationship or test the relationship? If it's a test, you should make a spec that runs a test along the lines of `it { should have_many(:histories) }`.... obviously depending on your testing framework.

If you're goal is to validate the has many relationship, you may need to write a custom validate method. However, can you share a little more about what exactly your trying to accomplish/what about the has_many relationship you are trying to validate?

Comment: I need to validate whether new record of associated object is created when updating the parent model.

Comment: I think what you want for this is simply a test, ensuring that the code is working, as it doesn't sound like a validation issue - unless your goal is to validate something like `instance has at least 1 history`.